# glScaled(size/window_size) incorrect image

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinate-transformation

When I use `glScale(size/window_size)` to draw a tetrahedron (window_size = 600x600) and input size = 600, it draws incorrect picture

[[image: Output][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGRNb.jpg).

When I input size < 600 it draws nothing, up to 1200 it draws the same images as given lower, after 1200 draws nothing again. How to do it correct?

```
int size_cat;
std::cin >> size_cat;
screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Jack.exe", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

int size_h = 2 * size_cat;

SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(screen);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glRotatef(25, 1, 1, 0);
while (1)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                return 0;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key.repeat) break;
                switch (event.key.keysym.scancode)
                {
                    case SDL_SCANCODE_1: glColor3b(127, 0, 0); break;
                    case SDL_SCANCODE_2: glColor3b(0, 127, 0); break;
                    case SDL_SCANCODE_3: glColor3b(0, 0, 127); break;
                }
                break;              
        }
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glScalef(size_cat/600, size_cat/600, size_cat/600);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glVertex3f(0.5, 1, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, -0.5);

    glVertex3f(0.5, 0 ,-0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);    

    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0, -0.5);

    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, -0.5);

    glVertex3f(0.5, 1, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);

    glVertex3f(0.5, 1, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0, -0.5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) in a loop, you are changing your matrix progressively. [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml) multiply the current matrix by a general scaling matrix.

See [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml):

> `glScale` produces a nonuniform scaling along the `x`, `y`, and `z` axes. The three parameters indicate the desired scale factor along each of the three axes.
>
> The current matrix (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)) is multiplied by this scale matrix, and the product replaces the current matrix.

Either use [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) to replace the current matrix with the identity matrix, before you do the scaling:

```
while (1)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(25, 1, 1, 0);
    glScalef(size_cat/600, size_cat/600, size_cat/600);

    .....
}
```

Or use [`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(25, 1, 1, 0);
while (1)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(size_cat/600, size_cat/600, size_cat/600);

    .....

    glPopMatrix();
}
```